# Top 2 max value from array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like

```
[ {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":117,"slide":4,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":12,"slide":1,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":8,"slide":3,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":7,"slide":2,"view":0}
];
```

I want to get 3 objects with top 3 values of duration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: so you want to get the top 3, sorted by duration length?

Comment: two or three top elements?

Answer (score 2):

You could sort them with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), descending and take the first three elements.

```js
var array = [{ id: 0, start: 0, duration: 7, slide: 2, view: 0 }, { id: 0, start: 0, duration: 12, slide: 1, view: 0 }, { id: 0, start: 0, duration: 117, slide: 4, view: 0 }, { id: 0, start: 0, duration: 8, slide: 3, view: 0 }],
    top3duration = array.sort(function (a, b) { 
        return b.duration - a.duration;
    }).slice(0, 3);

console.log(top3duration);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 yourArray.sort(function(a,b){ 
      return b.duration - a.duration;
 }).splice(0,3);

 console.log(yourArray);   // Will give top 3 objects of high duration.
```

But your mainArray will be modified. If you want those as new array then go with slice(0,3) and assign to a new array as [Fallenreaper's] answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var myList = [ {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":117,"slide":4,"view":0},
      {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":12,"slide":1,"view":0},
      {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":8,"slide":3,"view":0},
      {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":7,"slide":2,"view":0}
      ];

outList = myList.sort(function(a,b){ return b.duration - a.duration; }).slice(0,3);

return outList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do your stuff in a few quick steps.

```
var myList = [ {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":117,"slide":4,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":12,"slide":1,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":8,"slide":3,"view":0},
  {"id":0,"start":0,"duration":7,"slide":2,"view":0}
  ];
outList = myList.sort(function(a,b){ return b.duration - a.duration; }).slice(0,3);
return outList;
```